# Deploying Website with Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (iis)

Tags: iis, deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

I know this is a long shot but I'm going to ask anyway.

I have a project I'm working on for a company that hosts their application from a server running Microsoft Server 2012. I've found the folder where the web app's files are stored and I want to deploy my own version with updated code - would I just replace those files and restart the server to deploy? (after backing that folder up, of course)

This is super out of my wheelhouse as I've only used Github, Heroku, etc for deploying applications. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information to help you help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you host multiple websites on the same server.  Use IIS to point to another website and start it on a different port number for your web app.  Let me know if this isn't clear enough

Comment: There's only this one website being hosted. When I press explore, it shows me where the actual files are (HTML, CSS, JS). My question is if I replace those files with my updated files, will that update the website after I restart the server?

Comment: Don't do that....test it by running a 2nd version of the site using your code.  Take a look at this website for a step by step on how to setup IIS to run your own web code without disturbing the production website.  On another note, the production website is already setup on IIS to run its website.....I'm saying just add another website with your code to view how your code will behave

Answer (score 0):

If you only update HTML, CSS, JS these files, it will be updated after you restart the iis server, but if you change the cs file code you need to rebuild the project and republish it or just copy the bin folder.

Comment: Thank you for the reply - could you elaborate a little bit please? I'm not sure what you mean by cs file code. All I'm working with is front end JavaScript at the moment.

Comment: Files with the suffix .cs are usually class files